# SQL error convert nvarchar to numeric in a view

Tags: sql, type-conversion, azure-sql-database

I have the following table. The current column type of totalsales is `(nvarchar(max), null)`. The requirement is to change this column type to a numeric value in a SQL view.

I tried to do the following:

```
CAST([totalsales] AS numeric) AS [totalsales]
```

This statement doesn't work after I run the query on the view. Any suggestions? Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: What database are you using? And what kind of data is stored in that column currently?? Also: mind you that `NUMERIC` defaults to `NUMERIC(38,0)` - **no** digits after the decimal point - maybe you just need to specify something like `AS NUMERIC(20,2)` to get 2 fractional digits...

Comment: hi @ marc_s, its a Azure SQL database. The data in that column  contains info about sales for each store.

Comment: *doesn't work* doesn't explain anything about the problem. Do you get an error? Wrong values? Why on earth would you be using a varchar(max) for a column storing total sales - and why even *store* a sales total, which presumably is a moving target?

Comment: So basically you're using varchar because it can store "formatted" numbers... commas and  everything?

Comment: The error on SSMS describes "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric." The totalsales column is not a varchar but nvarchar. This table is generated by a Python script from a process which is made from Databricks Notebook.

Comment: @SalmanA This table is created from a automated Databricks process. This table is landed in a Azure SQL database as a Staging table. All columns are created with column type (nvarchar(max), null).  The requirement is to change the column types  to a numeric or decimal in a SQL view.

Comment: Do you have commas in numbers? If yes then fix the python script. If that is not an option, remove the commas (on demand) and convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **comma** **(,)** with empty and then convert to **numeric** (assuming this column will always have only numeric values).

```
select id, totalsales as totalsales_nvarchar
 ,cast(replace(totalsales, ',','') as numeric) AS totalsales_numeric 
from tb1
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Ok! Lets try this:

```
alter table <table_name> modify <column_name datatype>;
```

- for example:
  • Lets say we've created a table 'SAMPLE' with two columns 'ID' and 'NAME' having datatype as 'VARCHAR' each.(Here's the query)

  create table sample(id varchar(10), name varchar(20));

• But then we fond a flaw in it that the 'ID' column should have datatype as 'NUMBER'.

• Hence, we rectify our mistake by altering the table as==>>

```
alter table sample modify id number;
```

and when we describe table, now we have this;
ID column perfectly carrying a datatype as 'NUMBER'

```
TABLE SAMPLE
Column  Null?   Type
ID       -      NUMBER
NAME     -      VARCHAR2(20)
```

Comment: Azure SQL / SQL Server **doesn't** have an `ALTER TABLE () MODIFY ()` command...

Comment: Oh! I assumed so...